# How to change Atom Keybindings

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I am looking to change keybindings of Atom text editor. I am familiar with Android Studio.

Does Atom allow us to customize key bindings?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-do-i-create-keyboard-shortcuts/35861/2) .
`Why won't it let me just edit keyboard shortcuts from the menu like a normal editor?`
Because that's not how Atom was designed.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to go to Edit -> Preferences -> Keybinding. In this tab you can see your actual binding and if you want to change it, you can access to the keymap file and overcharged configuration.

To access this file you can click on the link below the "Keybindings" title.

For example, if you want to replace the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, search it in the list, click on the copy icon to copy the configuration line, and put the line into the keymap file and replace the shortcut.

For this example the new line is

```coffee
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-shift-Y': 'editor:delete-line'
```

This line replace `ctrl-shift-K` by `ctrl-shift-Y`. You have to relaunch Atom to apply this change.

Comment: What I have to write If I want to replace `Ctrl+Shift+K` functionality ?

Comment: To replace it you can write this line into your keymap file: `'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-shift-K': '[function to replace]'`

Comment: What to write in function? I want to replace with `Ctrl+Y`

Comment: function to replace is the name of the atom functionallity you want to trigger when you press on your keys. For example if I want to replace the new file shortcut my function name is `application:new-file`, consult the list into the keybindings tab.

Comment: I am not sure, bit confused can you write a snippet of lines I want to replace Ctrl+Shift+K to Ctrl+Y ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/3p1kq8bvyh8ky9v/keybinding.png?dl=0

Comment: yes sure. I will edit my response with this specific example.

Comment: How can list all the availble commands in order to a map a new key for them?

Comment: you can access to the keybinding list (Edit -> Preferences -> keybinding), you have the entire list of shortcuts and you can filter it with the searchbar.

Comment: I'm trying to edit multiple keybindings but every time I click the "copy" icon and paste in the keymap.cson it get's pasted as "atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])" so every time I try to save it complains of 'Duplicate key 'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])'". So what exacly goes in here?

Answer (score 3):

To override existing [atom keybindings](https://gist.github.com/brettz9/ea025c6357711f258bb2), just paste the new keybinding in

```
~/.atom/keymap.cson
```

If you want **emacs** keybindings for atom, get all the keybindings from,
https://github.com/dvorka/atom-editor-emacs-key-bindings/blob/master/keymap.cson

**TO APPLY:**

```
$ gedit ~/.atom/keymap.cson
```

gedit is the editor available in gnome, you can also use vi or emacs or even nano to edit.

```
$ vi ~/.atom/keymap.cson

$ emacs -nw ~/.atom/keymap.cson

$ nano ~/.atom/keymap.cson
```

modify, save & exit.
Restart atom, Done!

Comment: not useful unless you use gnome, not useful because not clear what to to paste in the file

Answer (score 1):

Building on Antoine's answer. Suppose you want to set up a shortcut to some command that you can get with the Command Palette (`Ctrl-Shift-p`). For example, I installed a package called "Pandoc Convert", and I wanted to set up the shortcut `Ctrl-r` for converting current file from markdown to PDF.

Step #1: Use the Command Palette to find your command. E.g. in my example, type "convert pdf". Use mouse to go over the command (but don't click). You'll see a tooltip with the name of the command. In my case "pandoc-convert:pdf".

Step #2. Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Keybinding, and click on the link at the top of the page to "your keymap file".

Step #3. Write the following in the keymap file, and save:

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-r': 'pandoc-convert:pdf'
```

(Obviously, replace the shortcut and the command with what you want.)

Done!

*Note:* This will overwrite the previous use of the shortcut. If you want the default behavior back, erase the stuff from the keymap file.

Answer (score 0):

I had conflicting key-bindings of Emmet and Line-Breaker, two essential tools for a programmer or writer. I am on Linux Debian derivative, with Atom 1.45 version.

I did not find the `keymap.cson` in my `~/.atom/` directory. Rather, I found keymaps in the `~/.atom/packages` subdirectory.

So to resolve my issue, I had updated the `~/.atom/packages/line-breaker/keymaps/line-breaker.cson` file, where I changed the key bindings.