# NSViewController.init(nibName:bundle:)

Tags: swift, nsviewcontroller

Overriding NSViewController.init(nibName...) can be overridden in an empty project, but not in my large one! How could my project affect that?

1. SETUP: I add the following into an empty project, and it compiles fine:

   ```
   class FooNsVc : NSViewController 
   override init(nibName nibNameOrNil:NSNib.Name?, bundle nibBundleOrNil:Bundle?) {
       super.init(nibName:nibNameOrNil, bundle:nibBundleOrNil)
       loadView()
   }
   }
   ```
2. ERROR: When I plop it into my application, I get compilation errors:`Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass`. **WHY**. I've removed all extensions of NSViewController and its superclasses NSResponder and NSObject. same symptoms.
3. FUNNY: Replacing the 2'nd and 3'rd lines with the following makes it compile.

   ```
     init(nibName nibNameOrNil:NSNib.Name?, bundle nibBundleOrNil:Bundle?) {
         super.init(nibName:nibNameOrNil, bundle:nibBundleOrNil)
   ```
4. But errors at `loadView()` with `could not load the nibName: is in  in bundle (null)` AtomInspector.xib exisits, it's shown in Assets/xib/AtomInspector.xib, copied there from a working OBJC project.
5. I started hacking, and after an hour I got the 18K lines of my app down to 3K. But the bug slipped away.

I did it again, the bug slipped away again.

Comment: How are you instanstiating `FooNsVc`? Does `FooNsVc` rely on `AtomInspector.xib`?

Comment: Actually, FooNsVC isn't instantiated at all! The compilation problem happens just defining it.

Comment: Additionally, I just included the xib in the "empty" project and instantiated FooNsVc() (in applicationDidFinishLaunching). It executes without error (although I do nothing with the resulting FooNsVc.)

Comment: The first code you showed does not compile, as it is missing a curly brace. But if we put that curly brace in, your code does compile as long as you also implement `init(coder:)`. So it's impossible to reproduce the issue based on what you have said.

Comment: Yes, the "{" is needed. Thanks. (It got lost in pasting stuff into stack overflow. (no emacs key bindings there) ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627165/how-to-change-atom-keybindings/43627306#43627306

Comment: BTW, thanks to whoever reformatted my code above. I should know how to do that, but don't.

Comment: YES, impossible to reproduce. I tried to cut my 18K lines down to a snippet, but failed twice. I was looking for hints on how to approach it.

Comment: UPDATE: In getting FooNsVc to use the .xib, I noticed a name conflict in my app, between Bundle (resources in NSBundle world) and Bundle (grouping of "factals" In my app). When moving my Bundle aside NSBundle world seemed happier (not sure why) and I could get FooNsVc()'s .xib loaded. After clearing up additional confusion about designated initializers for NsVc's, things are starting to work. So this problem is mostly resolved for me. Thanks for the help!